# New object instance copy method has undefined context. (sorry for misleading title)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am curios why this ES6 code outputs `undefined`:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  log() {
    console.log(this);
  }

}


const t = new Test('asd');
const asd = t.log;
asd();
```

but this ES5 code outputs `window`.

```js
 function Test(name) {
   this.name = name;
 }
 
 Test.prototype.log = function() {
   console.log(this)
 }
 
 const t = new Test('newer test');
 const asd = t.log;
 asd();
```

Techincally with something is invoked in the globar score it has window.thatSomething in front but apparently if thatSomething is a class there is no window.

Comment: The two are not equivalent - `class` stuff will be executed in strict mode by default. The second piece of code will behave the same if it was in strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `class` by default makes your code use [strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it/1335881#1335881). Normally, [the value of `this` will be assigned to the global object (`window`) if not determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) but in strict mode, it's set to `undefined` to prevent accidental problems like using properties of the global object:

```js
function sayName() {
  console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + "!");
}

function sayNameStrict() {
  "use strict";
  console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + "!");
}

let obj = {
  name: "Fred",
  sayName: sayName,
  sayNameStrict: sayNameStrict
}

obj.sayName(); //this = obj, this.name = "Fred

sayName(); //this = window, this.name = window.name

obj.sayNameStrict(); //this = obj, this.name = "Fred

sayNameStrict(); //this = undefined, this.name = TypeError
```

So, if you execute your second piece of code in strict mode, you'll get the same outcome as the ES6 class:

```js
"use strict";

function Test(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Test.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log(this)
}

const t = new Test('newer test');
const asd = t.log;
asd();
```